# Why is there a 20-pixel-high dark overlay over my app's navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Once again, I'm almost entirely sure this is something dumb that I'm doing, but I've been banging my head against this one for hours & am getting nowhere.

I'm trying to restructure the view hierarchy of my app. I need to be able to detect user interface orientation changes globally in order to correctly rotate a "Loading" view displayed when the app is downloading content. (device orientation changes seem to fire at different times, causing the view that needs to respond to these events to rotate sporadically).

The app previously added a UINavigationController's view to the main window. I modified the hierarchy to add the view of a UIViewController subclass to the main window, and added the view of the UINavigationController to the subclass's view. The UIViewController subclass manages the display & rotation of the "Loading" subview, and I was expecting the rest of the app to continue behaving normally, as inserting one extra empty view into the hierarchy didn't feel like I was changing too much.

My initial problem was the positioning of the UINavigationController - it was 20 pixels too low, resulting in a gap between the status bar and the navigation bar, and cutting off the bottom 20 pixels of the tab bar. I was able to adjust this by setting the frame property of the UINavigationController's view to the bounds property of the UIViewController's view, which corrected the position.

However, now I'm stuck with a 20-pixel-high dark "overlay" on top of my navigation bar. If I were to guess, I'd say it was black with 50% opacity. Touch events on this bar don't work (e.g. if I try to tap the "Back" button through the overlay, nothing happens). The fact that the height is equal to that of the status bar hasn't escaped me, but I'm at a total loss as to what could be causing it.

[image: Ridiculous navigation bar problem]

I hate feeling this stupid, so if anyone has any insight into this problem, you'd really make my day. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Posting code would help people help you.

Comment: It looks something to do with status bar, given the 20 pixel height. A little detail about IB/XIB file or source code would help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a few things pop out from your post.

> My initial problem was the positioning of the
>   UINavigationController - it was 20
>   pixels too low

This makes me believe it is related to your new problem.

> I was able to adjust this by setting
>   the frame property of the
>   UINavigationController's view to the
>   bounds property of the
>   UIViewController's view

This sounds like the view it was loaded onto was offset 20 pixels, and when you set it to the bounds, it repositioned it on the windows view space.

> Touch events on this bar don't work
>   (e.g. if I try to tap the "Back"
>   button through the overlay, nothing
>   happens)

This is the big thing. If touch events aren't being sent to the view, then what that means is that the OS doesn't see a view where you are pressing (or rather the view you want it to), so that view doesn't get the message to do something.

From what you have said, I believe your problem is with your base view controller that you just added. Try redoing the frame on, making it conform to where you want. Then take out the code you put in to set the navigation controllers frame. The navigation controller should fit to the view you added too, and once you have that main view where it needs to be (20 pixels higher apparently), then everything should work.